# Async HTML parser with Goutte

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle, goutte

I am trying to write HTML parser with the help of Goutte. It works very well. However [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) uses blocking requests. This works well if you are dealing with a single service. If I want to query lots of services which are independent from each other, this causes a problem. Goutte uses [BrowserKit](https://github.com/symfony/browser-kit) and [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle). I have tried to change doRequest function but it failed with

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\CookieJar::updateFromResponse() must be
>   an instance of Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response

```
 protected function doRequest($request)
    {
        $headers = array();
        foreach ($request->getServer() as $key => $val) {
            $key = strtolower(str_replace('_', '-', $key));
            $contentHeaders = array('content-length' => true, 'content-md5' => true, 'content-type' => true);
            if (0 === strpos($key, 'http-')) {
                $headers[substr($key, 5)] = $val;
            }
            // CONTENT_* are not prefixed with HTTP_
            elseif (isset($contentHeaders[$key])) {
                $headers[$key] = $val;
            }
        }

        $cookies = CookieJar::fromArray(
            $this->getCookieJar()->allRawValues($request->getUri()),
            parse_url($request->getUri(), PHP_URL_HOST)
        );

        $requestOptions = array(
            'cookies' => $cookies,
            'allow_redirects' => false,
            'auth' => $this->auth,
        );

        if (!in_array($request->getMethod(), array('GET', 'HEAD'))) {
            if (null !== $content = $request->getContent()) {
                $requestOptions['body'] = $content;
            } else {
                if ($files = $request->getFiles()) {
                    $requestOptions['multipart'] = [];

                    $this->addPostFields($request->getParameters(), $requestOptions['multipart']);
                    $this->addPostFiles($files, $requestOptions['multipart']);
                } else {
                    $requestOptions['form_params'] = $request->getParameters();
                }
            }
        }

        if (!empty($headers)) {
            $requestOptions['headers'] = $headers;
        }

        $method = $request->getMethod();
        $uri = $request->getUri();

        foreach ($this->headers as $name => $value) {
            $requestOptions['headers'][$name] = $value;
        }

        // Let BrowserKit handle redirects
            $promise = $this->getClient()->requestAsync($method,$uri,$requestOptions);
            $promise->then(
                function (ResponseInterface $response) {
                    return $this->createResponse($response);

                },
                function (RequestException $e) {
                    $response = $e->getResponse();
                    if (null === $response) {
                        throw $e;
                    }


                }



            );
        $promise->wait();

    }
```

How can I change Goutte\Client.php so that it does requests asynchronously? Is that is not possible, how can I run my scrappers which targets different endpoints simultaneously? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Goutte is essentially a bridge between Guzzle and Symphony's Browserkit and DomCrawler.

The biggest drawback with using Goutte is that all requests are made sychronouslly

To complete things asychronously you will have to forego using Goutte and directly use Guzzle and DomCrawler.

For example:

```
$requests = [
    new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $uri[0]),
    new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $uri[1]),
    new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $uri[2]),
    new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $uri[3]),
    new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $uri[4]),
    new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $uri[5]),
    new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $uri[6]),
];

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$pool = new GuzzleHttp\Pool($client, $requests, [
    'concurreny' => 5, //how many concurrent requests we want active at any given time
    'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) {
        $crawler = new Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler(null, $uri[$index]);
        $crawler->addContent(
            $response->getBody()->__toString(),
            $response->getHeader['Content-Type'][0]
        );        
    },
    'rejected' => function ($response, $index) {
        // do something if the request failed.
    },
]);

$promise = $pool->promise();
$promise->wait();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I am trying to run separate scrappers which has more than simple get requests. Each scrapper has its own class to do series of requests,DOM parsing etc. That is why I wonder, how can I call all these scrappers asynchronously. If my scrappers are localhost/site1.php localhost/site2.php, is it a good idea to call site1.php ,site2.php from lets say cron.php with above code ? What do you suggest?